# Compound Interest Formula in SwiftUI

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I convert this formula intro code in SwiftUI

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let A = pow(P * (1 + r / n), n * t)
```

I tried it with these values in a playground

```
let P = 2.0
let r = 0.2
let n = 2.0
let t = 5.0
let A = pow(P * (1 + r / n), n * t)
```

and got this value for A:

```
2655.99227914
```